# How can i get an image next to a Text?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PersonalData extends StatelessWidget {
  final String Name;
  final String Alter;
  final String urlImage;

  PersonalData(this.Name, this.Alter, this.urlImage);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(Name),),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("Name: " + Name, textAlign: TextAlign.left),
            new Text("Alter: " + Alter),
            new Image.network(urlImage, height: 200.0, width: 200.0, alignment: Alignment.topRight,),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

How can i get the Image near the Text. at the moment the Text stays left and the Image is under the Text on the right

Comment: Check out the layout tutorial https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/

Comment: You're not describing what you want it to look like very well - maybe a picture would help as it's not clear what you actually want this to look like. But I second @RichardHeap's comment - it seems as though you might not understand how flutter's layout system works very well. The image is in exactly the position you tell it to be right now.

Answer (score 5):

I think your should search fultter docs and library more this is a basic requirement and they have provided it nicely:

```
Widget _getUserDetailsWidget() {
    var assetImage = AssetImage("assets/png/cat.jpg");
    var image = new Image(image: assetImage, height: 96.0, width: 96.0, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,);
    final ListTile listTile = new ListTile(title: new Text("Silent Sudo"),
    leading: image, subtitle: new Text("Location: India"));
    return listTile;
  }
```

Replace `new Container() => _getUserDetailsWidget()`

Answer (score 0):

Use Row() inside this column .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).